# How to find the memory leak from the two heap snapshot comaparison in Node JS

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, node-inspector, node-memwatch

[image]

From this image, How can I proceed to find the memory leak in my Node JS server? Can anyone help me the steps or how to start look from this heap snapshot comparison?